# Is it possible to use FyTest in Microsoft Visual Studio without CMake?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, fortran

I am developing on an old legacy code in Fortran, and I am trying to implement unit testing to enable a more secure development environment. From all the options given in the Fortran Wiki on [this page](https://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Unit+testing+frameworks), I evaluated FyTest would be the most suitable one.

However, to automatically run the tests, it needs a CMake build instruction, which currently I don't have installed on the company computer (I could ask for its necessity, but that is a long and tiresome process I am trying to avoid). The company software for development is Microsoft Visual Studio (version 2010). Is there a way "native" to Visual Studio for running FyTest? I noticed that creating a project in Visual Studio creates a "solution file" (`.sln`), but I don't know if it is possible to adapt it to do the same work as CMake would do...

Comment: You should be able to compile cmake from source without needing administrator permissions.

Comment: You don't need to build CMake by your own or have administrative rights to run and install CMake on your computer. Download the [zip file](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.23.2/cmake-3.23.2-windows-x86_64.zip) for version 3.23.2 from CMake.org and place it in a folder of your home direcrory. Add the `bin` folder to your PATH variable and you are done. But that still might violate the company terms of software use.

Comment: I discovered you can install it through `pip`. I was authorized to use `pip`, as long as it was to install stuff only in my own machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native support for **FyTest** is VS2010, nor in any other VS version. Your best option would be bundeling the **FyTest** `CMakeLists.txt` into your CMake project (there is no direct dependency between your selected IDE and the CMake project for that matter).

Comment: The problem being I can't install CMake on the company computer...

Comment: My guess is that you, or someone similar to you, will have to fight the `cmake` battle sooner or later ... Once fought and one I also suspect it will be useful in other projects in the future